# How to write undefined number of lines to file after it found a segment between two line matches in Python

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I have this text file:

```
line 1
line 2
test = {
line 3
line 4
...
line n
}
}
line n+1
```

I am trying to write the file as it is with the exception of changing when i find the part starting with test:

```
line 1
line 2
test = edited({
line 3
line 4
...
line n
})
line n+1
```

test = { and } will always be there so i am trying to match these two as start and end parameters.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


a = False
mystartingword ="test = {"

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if mystartingword in line:
            print("Old label = value: " + line)
            new_line ='test = edited({' + '\n'
            a = True
            f.write(new_line)
        elif "}" in line:
            if a == True:
                new_line = ")}"
                f.write(new_line)
                a = False
            else:
                f.write(line)
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

It is important i only change the first occurence of the } because it belongs to the test line.

How do i write the lines 3 ... n and have a trigger to stop changing after the first } in a more elegant way?

Thank you!

Comment: why starting word is `"labels = {"`?, where is `lines`?, the first `f.write()` is wrongly indented, why `if a == True` when `a = False` then the if statement never run.

Comment: Correct, i made some changes to it, but forgot to update it. I am still trying to get this to work more properly.

Comment: Your code is working, isn't it? So what's the question?

Comment: Is there a way to make this more elegant? More programmatic? More efficient? I am a beginner and this was the first thing i thought of so i was wondering about other options.